# What temperatures can be tolerated by a ''small'' human?

Tags: biology, humans, temperature, cyborg, metabolism

Temperature resistance is linked to size and bodily composition.
An easy example is the small obesity rate in cities like Singapore, regardless of the modernized diet fat people don't hang around in a country which has 4 seasons of tropical hyper-humid summer, it is already too hot there for tinny people.

This question is related to [>>](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/206874/does-a-cyborg-have-the-need-for-a-toilette)

A cyborg is now roughly 30% of what it used to be, they are about only 16 kilograms of bio-matter.

What is the lowest temperature they could withstand for a lengthy time?

I came to understand that human flesh survives better in situations where the temperature is either too hot or too cold, weak cells die leaving only the sane and young ones to survive. Extreme temperatures count as a mild-chemotherapy in a sense.

The reason the character is throwing away their flesh like an used tissue, is the aspiration for longevity and escapism from the frail and weak side of life, Does this justify the question?

This is why I need to know the limit temperatures the cyborg can resist, the maximum amount of stress that can kill the weak cells but not all the cells.

Comment: I don't know where you have read that human flesh survives better in situations where the temperature is either too hot or too cold, it just sounds terribly wrong. Ask any frost bite or burn  amputee if they are younger and healthier.

Comment: @L.Dutch https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2574693/

Comment: @L.Dutch https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4486781/

Comment: @L.Dutch https://www.futurity.org/cold-weather-lifespan-genes-1943492/

Comment: @L.Dutch https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2020/03/200311100857.htm

Comment: you are either born adaptable and survive high stress, growing stronger, or have to become slowly more and more adaptable... in some cases, people are just born weak and hopeless with no room for improvement.

Comment: @L.Dutch another example of stress being a good source of longevity are blood donors, losing blood is a stress for the body, yet blood donors live longer, even when accounting for smoking, exercise, sex life, gender and diet.

Comment: Those studies are testing differences of decimal celsius of temperature. The second Articles tested differences of 0.3 Celsius degrees in mammals. The other tests with larger differences were made using animals that have fur, which helps control their internal body temperature.

Comment: Also, they noticed that there was a change on metabolism speed and another ageing properties, but they did not take in account side effects from extreme temperatures exposition. Ex. Dehydration will specially affect your kidneys increasing the risk of stones. Low temperatures will weaken your body in aspects enough for me to not be able to write it in one comment.

Comment: Too hot means the body is constantly under stress trying to keep itself cool, wasting more resources and energy. Too cool means the body is constantly under stress trying to keep itself warm, again wasting more resources and energy. If subjecting the body to extreme temperature was actually beneficial, hyperthermia and hypothermia would not be conditions known to be dangerous (assuming a base core temperature of 36,5 degrees celsius, it takes a drop of over 1.5 degrees celsius on average in your core temperature for you to be diagnosed with hypothermia, 3,5 degrees for hyperthermia).

Comment: Also, if people who have no arms and legs are something to go by, chances are that your cyborg, assuming they keep a normal human metabolism and core temperature, should have more problems with passive thermoregulation than a normal person, since our limbs play a pretty important role in dissipating extra heat (see how one of the most common strategies to help with the cold is to put yourself in a position that keeps your limbs as close to your body as possible).

Comment: The most important part of one portion of the first article is "A controlled and balanced dietary regimen is, to date, the most effective way to prolong lifespan and retard aging" It mentioned mostly that the reduced body temperature caused increased calorie consumption allowing for a better controlled diet. So really, these effects are from proper diet concerns as a SIDE EFFECT not a main effect of cold.

Answer (score 3):

It's a cyborg. Normal biological constraints don't apply, since they have access to an artificial energy source. They can route their blood through a thermo regulating unit, heating or cooling it as required.

I would expect them then to withstand a much wider range of temperatures than an unaugmented human.

Also, if they removed their arms, legs, and ears, which are a problem in cold weather due to their large surface area,  they have much less problems with freezing extremities.

Answer (score 1):

**What is the lowest temperature they could withstand for a lengthy time?**

The real answer is just as much time as a normal person. The only difference that being a cyborg gives is as follows:

**Mechanical heating/cooling.**

The cyborg could exist in lower temperatures for as long as their energy sources hold out if they had the proper climate control for their squishy interior portions. They would still sustain damage if their core temp had a variance of ~1.5-3.5 degrees Celsius.

**Reduced Exposure Area**

The area exposed to the elements would provide a significant benefit when exposed to cold (less heat loss) but, would provide a significant downside when exposed to heat (less heat loss).

**Is being a cyborg useful for prolonging life?**

Probably **not.** This doesn't change the aging of *any* internal organs that need to work. The reduced stress from activity might actually reduce the lifespan due to lack of use in the same way that sedentary lifestyles are harmful.